# Calculating predicted values for all categories using tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

This question relates to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331427/predicting-from-list-using-lapply).

I am running a similar model as in that question, but at the last line I would like to have 7 predicted columns (i.e. change the dataset in a way that in the first case the new dataset group=0, in the second group=1, etc.

```
# Code from the original question
library(dplyr)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out=10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace=T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- data.frame(year=year, group=group, value=value, female=female, smoker=smoker)

# cut the dataset into list
table_list <- dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  group_split()

# fit model per subgroup
model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) glm(smoker ~ female*group, data=x,
                                                 family=binomial(link="probit")))

# create new dataset where group =1
dat_new0 <- data.frame(dta[, c("smoker", "year", female)], group=0) 
dat_new1 <- data.frame(dta[, c("smoker", "year", female)], group=1) 
dat_new2 <- data.frame(dta[, c("smoker", "year", female)], group=2)

etc.
 

pred0 <- predict.glm(dat_new0, type = "response")
pred1 <- predict.glm(dat_new1, type = "response")
pred2 <- predict.glm(dat_new2, type = "response")

etc.
```

Instead of doing this by hand, I would like to use tidymodels somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use [broom](/questions/tagged/broom) for this. First, use `nest()` to split your data into the groupings you want to use for modeling and then `map()` over them to train your models:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out=10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- tibble(year = year, group = group, female = female, smoker = smoker)

mods <- dta %>%
    nest(data = c(-year)) %>%
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(smoker ~ female*group, data = .,
                                 family = binomial(link = "probit"))))

mods
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>    year data                 model 
#>   <int> <list>               <list>
#> 1  2014 <tibble [5,000 × 3]> <glm> 
#> 2  2015 <tibble [5,000 × 3]> <glm>
```

Now use `crossing()` from [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) to create your new example data:

```r
new_dat <- crossing(smoker = 0:1, female = 0:1, year = 2014:2015, group = 0:2)
new_dat
#> # A tibble: 24 × 4
#>    smoker female  year group
#>     <int>  <int> <int> <int>
#>  1      0      0  2014     0
#>  2      0      0  2014     1
#>  3      0      0  2014     2
#>  4      0      0  2015     0
#>  5      0      0  2015     1
#>  6      0      0  2015     2
#>  7      0      1  2014     0
#>  8      0      1  2014     1
#>  9      0      1  2014     2
#> 10      0      1  2015     0
#> # … with 14 more rows
```

Then predict for this new example data on each of your trained models. (I used `augment()` here from broom so that the new predicted column gets added on to the existing columns, but you could also use `predict()`).

```
mods %>%
    mutate(preds = map(model, augment, newdata = new_dat))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>    year data                 model  preds            
#>   <int> <list>               <list> <list>           
#> 1  2014 <tibble [5,000 × 3]> <glm>  <tibble [24 × 5]>
#> 2  2015 <tibble [5,000 × 3]> <glm>  <tibble [24 × 5]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Once you have these predictions, you can `unnest()` them and then handle them however you like.